# 2056-6363/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

First of all, apologies if I am repeating a question, or doing anything incorrectly...-It is my first time here after all ;)

I am working on gesture-based no-touch smartphone navigation for a university project, and in my current step I keep encountering "Couldn't load memtrack module" error when the emulator is running. I tried changing emulator, same result. What is strange to me is that the app works flawlessly, but the error is concerning to me nonetheless. I would be happy if someone could elaborate to me why it is happening & possible help me get rid of it.

Kind regards. Mikkel

PS: I don't get the "(No such file or directory) that all the other memtrack module posts have.[Logcat readings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbVOI.png)